# Algebra Problem regarding powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

if $a \gt b$ prove that $a^3+2ab^2\gt b^3+2a^2b$

Comment: Hint: $a^3+2ab^2=a(a^2+2b^2)$.

Comment: But how do I get to the latter one from the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$
a^3-b^3+2ab^2-2a^2b>0
$$
or, collecting terms,
$$
(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)-2ab(a-b)>0
$$
that becomes
$$
(a-b)(a^2-ab+b^2)>0
$$
Since $a-b>0$, this inequality is equivalent to
$$
a^2-ab+b^2>0
$$
or
$$
4a^2-4ab+4b^2>0
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
(2a-b)^2+3b^2>0
$$
This is a true relation, because it can only be false if
$$
2a-b=0 \quad\text{and}\quad b=0
$$
but this is excluded by $a>b$.

Answer (score 1):

As this is obvious if $b=0$, or  if $a>0, b<0$. Thus we may suppose $b\ne 0$ and $a,b$ have the same sign.

We'll set $t=\dfrac ab$.

- If $a,b >0$, rewrite the inequality as 
  $$t^3+2t>1+2t^2\iff t3-2t^2+2t=(t^2-2t+2)t>1$$
  under the hypothesis $t>1$. This is a consequence of $t>1$ and
  $$t^2-2t+2>1\iff t^2-2t+1>0.$$
- If $a, b<0$, , set $a'=-a,\enspace b'=-b$. Now we have $b'>a'>0$, so by the first case 
  $$ b'^3+2a'b'^2=-(b^3+2ab^2)>a'^3+2a'b'^2=-(a^3+2ab^2),$$
  whence the same conclusion.

Comment: Can you please explain/elaborate how you got the first inequality containing t? $t^3+2t>1+2t^2$

Comment: Where in the problem is it stated that $b>0$?

Comment: @egreg: You're right. I've adapted my answer. Thanks for pointing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If $b\gt0$ we have $$a\gt b\Rightarrow a^3\gt b^3 \\\text{and}\ 2a\gt2b\Rightarrow\\ 2a^2\gt2ab\Rightarrow2a^2b\gt 2ab^2$$

By adding the $2$ inequalities we get $$a^3+2a^2b\gt b^3+2ab^2$$ as desired.

If $b\lt 0$ we have $$a\gt b\Rightarrow a^3\gt b^3 \\\text{and}\ 2a\gt2b\Rightarrow\\ 2a^2\color{red}\lt2ab\Rightarrow2a^2b\gt 2ab^2$$

As in the first case, by adding the $2$ inequalities we get $$a^3+2a^2b\gt b^3+2ab^2$$ as desired.